# Discrepancies in document activity timing

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, version-history

I am using SharePoint Online and have noticed the activity section of the details pane for a document showing different modified times to the version history of the same document.

For example:

Joe Bloggs modified this document at 'reasonable time' in the version history

Document Details - Activity - Joe Bloggs edited this file at 03:15 am.

I have regional settings set to my time zone etc.

Does anyone know why there is this discrepancy and the two fields don't use the same time?
[image]

Comment: Where are you referring to the activity section of the details pane? Please offer a screenshot to further troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Zacc, how are the documents being moved into this document library? If you are **moving documents from a source doc library into this library** they will retain their original "Created" and "Created by" metadata, even after you move them into the new library. (But in the "Information" blade, the created date for the entry in the new doc library will be the date it moved in.)

Take a look at this example. My colleague, Derek, created a file in a document library back in April. Today (in August), I (Emily) performed a "Move to" from that source doc library into a new doc library. Notice that the metadata retains Derek as the creator and retains the April 7 "Created" date, but in the "Activity" (Information) blade, you can see the file was created today.
[image]